# How to fix "Container cuts another container" problem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If I set the height of the green container to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2` it's work as expected, But set the height of the green container to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3` causes the green container to cut the blue container.

How do I get over this?

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[      
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 80,
            right: 30,
            left: 30,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 400.0,
            ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the green container is working as the "main screen" and it's positioning the rest of the Stack children into it.

So... I just wrapped the main Container into a Column (I think you could use any multi-child layout) and it works as expected.

```
body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 80,
        right: 30,
        left: 30,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: 200,
          width: 400.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Hope it helps you.